# Changing size of Windows partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, disk

when I was installing Linux, I divided my HDD into few partitions. By mistake, I let for Windows too little space. Question is, how to uninstall Linux, join all partitions and then again divide HDD into few partitions of different size and install Linux WITHOUT uninstalling the Windows.

Comment: To help you better, can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: I'm on Windows right now. I'll post it in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem but you can also resize partitions with **Partition manager** and in Windows 7 or Vista you can use **Disk Management**. There are also lots of other programs that will do this, you can use Ubuntu from the USB stick...

In **partition manager** you have first (right click on the parition) and **Unmount** neighboring partitions  and then resize  them with resize/Move button.

You don't have to reinstall anything to do that.

Comment: But how do I change size of Windows partition and Linux partition? Because only thing what I can do is delete Linux partition, or shrink Windows partition

Comment: The linux partition mustn't be mounted. In order to achieve this, you have to use a liveCD or LiveUSB stick. PartedMagic for example. Or the Ubuntu install cd

Comment: The best way would be to use ubuntu from the USB stick. This is how I did it some weeks ago. 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick